# Como criar rotas em App usando Ionic e Angulas.js?

Tags: angularjs, ionic, route

EDITADO

Consegui criar rotas com um exemplo do próprio site.

Porém notei que os controllers ficam no mesmo arquivo principal `app.js` e as views fica no arquivo `index.html`.

Gostaria de saber se tem como separar esse conteúdo em arquivos diferentes, onde cada tela ficasse em um arquivo html próprio com seu arquivo js próprio.

Ex:

index.html | app.js
 home.html  | home.js
 help.html  | help.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiago, o Ionic utiliza o ui-router como provider para as rotas.

O que você quer fazer é possível.

Exemplo:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  var helloState = {
    name: 'hello',
    url: '/hello',
    template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
  }
  
  var aboutState = {
    name: 'about',
    url: '/about',
    template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>'
  }
  
  $stateProvider.state(helloState);
  $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//npmcdn.com/show-current-browser-url"></script>
    <script src="//npmcdn.com/angular@latest/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//npmcdn.com/angular-ui-router@1.0.0-alpha.4/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    
    <script src="helloworld.js"></script>
    <style>.active { color: red; font-weight: bold }</style>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-app="helloworld">
    <a ui-sref="hello" ui-sref-active="active">Hello</a>
    <a ui-sref="about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a>
    
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Segue a documentação:
https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng1/helloworld

Answer (score 3):

Amigo, você precisa dar uma olhada na documentação do ionic pois possui bastante referência acerca do assunto.

Para criar seus arquivos html para cada view que necessite é bastante simples você pode sim criar esses arquivos que são os templates no iônic.

Se você criar um app usando o comando do ionic usando o template "tabs" vai poder ver como funciona:

```
$ ionic start myApp tabs
```

Dentro da pasta www terá uma pasta templates e lá contém as views respectivas a cada "rota".